# ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis Hrk

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying a below code on oracle database

```sql
select *
from (
    select 
        LBRCODE,
        PRDACCTID,
        (
            CASE
                WHEN to_char(CBLDATE, 'dd-mon-yyyy') <> '01-jan-2021'
                THEN to_date('01-jan-2021', 'dd-mon-yyyy')
                ELSE CBLDATE
            END
        ) AS CBLDATE,
        BALANCE1,
        BALANCE2,
        BALANCE3,
        BALANCE4,
        rank() over(
            partition by lbrcode, prda cctid order by cbldate desc
        ) rnk
    from cbl 
    WHERE CBLDATE <= '01-jan-2021'
)
where rnk = 1
```

I am getting the error `ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis`
What I am missing here?
Please help

Answer (score 1):

`prda cctid` in the `RANK` analytic function does not match `prdacctid` you used previously in the select list; my guess is that you have a typo of an additional space which needs removing. If they are two columns then you need a comma between them.

You can also use `DATE` literals so that you are not relying on implicit and explicit casts to/from strings:

```sql
select *
from   (
         select LBRCODE,
                PRDACCTID,
                (CASE
                 WHEN CBLDATE <  DATE '2021-01-01'
                 OR   CBLDATE >= DATE '2021-01-01' + INTERVAL '1' DAY
                 THEN DATE '2021-01-01'
                 ELSE CBLDATE
                 END
                ) AS CBLDATE,
                BALANCE1,
                BALANCE2,
                BALANCE3,
                BALANCE4,
                rank() over(
                  partition by lbrcode, prdacctid  -- remove the space here
                  order by cbldate desc
                ) rnk
         from   cbl 
         WHERE  CBLDATE <= DATE '2021-01-01'
)
where rnk=1
```

Given that your `WHERE` filter will filter out any values that are after `2021-01-01 00:00:00` then you can simplify the code further to:

```sql
select *
from   (
         select LBRCODE,
                PRDACCTID,
                DATE '2021-01-01' AS CBLDATE,
                BALANCE1,
                BALANCE2,
                BALANCE3,
                BALANCE4,
                rank() over(
                  partition by lbrcode, prdacctid  -- remove the space here
                  order by cbldate desc
                ) rnk
         from   cbl 
         WHERE  CBLDATE <= DATE '2021-01-01'
)
where rnk=1
```